# How to improve the 3D effect of this plot? (TikZ and pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have been experimenting with plots for a particular data series I have generated. The code below plots a surface around a polar axis reading in data from a file. The file can be downloaded here (test.dat):

http://expirebox.com/download/bfeeb6e62597b92808a625fd03f80974.html

It looks "ok" but I feel it can be made to look better. I know TikZ is not the best option for 3D plotting, but I wanted to test its capabilities and I felt it would be faster to do it in TikZ/pgfplots rather than Asymptote.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view={180}{10},
      %axis equal,
      axis x line=middle,
      axis y line=middle,
      axis z line=middle,
      %hide y axis,
      hide x axis,
      ytick=\empty,
      zticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
      data cs=polar,
      ]
      \foreach \r in {0,1,...,4} {
        \addplot+[domain=0:180,mark=none,black,samples=200, smooth, solid] (\x, \r);
      }
      %% Dummy white circle to stop the angle labels being cut off  by the 3-D environment.
      \addplot+[domain=0:180,mark=none,white,samples=200, smooth, solid] (\x, 6);
      \foreach \thetta in {0,30,...,180} {
        \edef\doplot{\noexpand\addplot+[domain=0:4,mark=none,black, solid]  (\thetta, \noexpand\x) node[pos=1.25]  {\thetta};}
        \doplot
      }

      \addplot3[surf, z buffer=sort,mesh/ordering=y varies,opacity=0.8,colormap/blackwhite] table[x index={1},y index={0},z index={2},
      opacity=0.]{test.dat};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

The issue is that certain viewing angles the polar axis and z-axis do not look perpendicular to one another, or the "depth" aspect is missing. If it is not possible to modify it in TikZ, what would be the best way to go about it using Asymptote etc...?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Applying Zoxume's suggestion results in the following. This does display the information in a more logical format. It would be nice to have both the 3D surface shot and the above shot.

[image]

Comment: Why not doing it in 2D with a colormap that represents the “height”? Plus, with an semi-circle, you can read the angles correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have modified the post with the 2D version you suggested.